# Mapstruct inherit and extract from child mapper

Tags: java, spring-boot, inheritance, mapstruct

I have an audit object to record `created`, `updated` and `creator` three attribute, looks like below:

```
public class Audit {
    private OffsetDateTime created;
    private OffsetDateTime updated;
    private String creator;
}
```

each POJO has audit attribute

```
public class A {
    private Audit audit;
}
public class B {
    private Audit audit;
}
public class C {
    private Audit audit;
}
```

...etc

Now, I want to ask how can I create an reusable model and mapper to extract `created`, `updated` and `creator` to parent layer (maybe inherit or some annotation) like below result:

```
// Before mapping
A {
    ...,
    audit: {
        created: ...,
        updated: ...,
        creator: ...
    }
}
// I wanna to mapping like these
A {
    ...
    created: ...,
    updated: ...,
    creator: ...
}
B {
    ...
    created: ...,
    updated: ...,
    creator: ...
}
C {
    ...
    created: ...,
    updated: ...,
    creator: ...
}
```

Or I must to use `@Mapping(source = audit.created, target = created)` annotation for all mapper for these class?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that I understand you correctly. However, MapStruct 1.4.0.Beta3 defined ducktyping. You can make your own annotation as shorthand for `@Mapping(source = audit.created, target = created)` See the [documentation](https://mapstruct.org/documentation/dev/reference/html/#mapping-composition).

In 1.3.x you need to define a common base type for your target / source and you can inherit the mapping from a base mapping method. Checkout the [documentation](https://mapstruct.org/documentation/stable/reference/html/#_reusing_mapping_configurations).

Comment: Thanks for reply. But I really want to find a method like interface or something converter to auto faltten audit object without using `@Mapping(source = audit.created, target = created)` and others for all object apply audit.